# Rotating animation for UIImageView rotates something else

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

My code so far is

```
rotateButton = [UIButton new];
    rotateButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [rotateButton setFrame:CGRectMake(334, 80, 100, 20)];
    [rotateButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rotateImageView:Degrees:InTimePeriod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [rotateButton setTitle:@"Rotate" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:rotateButton];

-(void)rotateImageView
{
    [self rotateImageView:imageView Degrees:90 InTimePeriod:1.5];
}

-(void)rotateImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView Degrees:(NSInteger)degrees InTimePeriod:(float)time
{
    CABasicAnimation *rotate;
    rotate = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    rotate.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    rotate.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees)];
    rotate.duration = time;
    rotate.repeatCount = 1;
    [imageView.layer addAnimation:rotate forKey:@"Rotate"];
}
```

However, the button that I use to start the rotating is the object that rotates after I press the button, not the imageView I want it to rotate. How do I make the imageView rotate instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 [rotateButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rotateImageView:Degrees:InTimePeriod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

you set the @selector(rotateImageView:Degrees:InTimePeriod:) as the action of the button.The button send him self as the first argument to @selector(rotateImageView:Degrees:InTimePeriod:) as default,in fact,when the function is running,the *imageView is point to the button,that's why the button rotated but the imageView.Do as aeubanks say.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    [rotateButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rotateImageView:Degrees:InTimePeriod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

to

```
    [rotateButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rotateImageView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: In that case you have a bug somewhere. You should probably not be accessing imageView directly, instead do it like this: [self rotateImageView:self.imageView Degrees:90 InTimePeriod:1.5];